# What do you do to initiate and hold the edge during a carved turn on a snowboard?

Tags: technique, snowboarding

I've read many books and many posts on other snowboarding forums, but there is always something new to learn from more experienced riders. I switch to the new edge just as I cross the fall line but frequently skid during the second half of the turn and into the new traverse. For me this is mostly a problem on toe side turns.